# pair production of different families

Tags: pair-production

I know that we have a few different conservation laws. Energy, lepton number, conservation and charge. We also cannot have pair production without the presence of a nucleus, however, in my head, none of these requirements prevent the possibility of having the following pair productions.

\begin{equation}
\gamma \rightarrow \mu^+ + e^-\\
\gamma \rightarrow e^+ + \mu^-
\end{equation}

Is there something which causes these not to be allowed? Or do we just have to have incredibly high energy photons?

Comment: [Electromagnetic interactions conserve flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)#Leptons).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That could be an answer with a few more words ;P